# removing sugar / dead yeasts / residues from keg

Tags: yeast, kegging, temperature, sugar, residual

Due to some CO2 cylinder carbonation problems I have resorted to the desperate method of pouring sugar into the keg. Which is probably bad, as I have found out [here](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/23649/kegged-cider-co2-foam-not-much-sparkle-though) all I needed was lower temperatures and appropriate tubing.

Fortunately, my sugarized keg did not start fermenting due to the lowish temperatures in the room it is deposited in. I should mention that there was some carbonation in the keg when I have poured the sugar (I got a geyser out of it at pouring time). What should I best do now  ?

a) rack it and re-attempt the pressure-carbonation at lower temps ?

b) move the keg to higher temp, let it ferment the sugar and then

> b1) move it to lower temps and leave it like that
>
> b2) rack it off the dead yeasts then move it to lower temps, and lose lots of acid in the process

Or else ?

Comment: Did you put sugar in a keg of *beer* to do a bottle-like carbonation?  (which is a known method)

Comment: @Kingsley of cider, yes, that's what I have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you put the correct amount of priming sugar into a keg for natural carbonation.

Just to keep it simple, I would simply close off the keg, and leave it somewhere to keep the yeast warm for 2 weeks.  This should ferment out the sugar, *and* carbonate the keg.

The next step is to refrigerate for a while to drop-out the yeast.

Finally, tap the keg.  The first few glasses will have most of the yeast from the bottom of the keg, but after that it should be mostly OK.

It's your beverage, so if you want to decant it off the excess sugar, etc. etc. then do that instead.  But at least some of the sugar will have dissolved, and will re-ferment, even at low temperatures.

Comment: hmm, there already is too much xylithol in it so I don't want it any sweeter. "The first few glasses will have most of the yeast from the bottom of the keg" - brilliant!

Comment: but ... I think I have put more sugar than the chart said.Maybe some 20% extra. That's one issue. The other is that the chart spcified the sugar quantity for 17 C. Since there has been no fermentation at 17 degrees C I will be moving the cider keg to 22 C. Is there any danger of it going kaboom ?

Comment: @kellogs - if there was too much sugar added, just let it ferment for a day or so first.  17C is not a too-low temperature for ale yeast fermentation. A temperature of >= 15C is the generally recommended *lower-limit* for ale yeast performance.  Does your keg have a pressure-release valve?  I would *guess* it would be OK, but just release some excess pressure if you're concerned.

Comment: I don't know, my keg has been sitting there for weeks, no fermentation. "just let it ferment for a day or so first" - and then ? No, the keg doesnt have that. But I could use the couple which is connected to thecylinder regulator which does have relief valve.